# How to get the value of html input in aspx view page in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to access the radio button value in aspx view page in middle of the logic.if value is checked i need to run for each loop to get the values or if radio button is unchecked no need of getting the values.
How to get the value of radio button in aspx view engine ?

Comment: Side note: reading values from request directly in the view rendering is not good practice - consider doing it in controller.

Comment: based on that radio selection that view i need to seperate it as two differnet ways.if radio is checked show all values of view but if radio not checked to show only some required values in view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your title I get that you are using Asp.net MVC, if it is right you can define a parameter in your action method with the ID of your radiobutton, and MVC model binder will handle the remaining, you can use the parameter to check and run the loop.